# Change Node.js version for extensionHost debugger type in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-oracledb

I'm developing a VSCode extension which queries an Oracle database instance via [oracledb npm](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb)

[vscode-database](https://github.com/Bajdzis/vscode-database) extension was taken as a basis.

Node version installed is 8.9.4. Test script, which checks connection with Oracle works fine:

```
-> node -v
8.9.4
-> node connect.js
ok
```

But when I'm trying to debug the VSCode extension with the same connection script, I get error:

> Activating extension bajdzis.vscode-database failed: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 7.9.0 (win32, x64)

The error says Node.js 7.9.0 is utilizing, not 8.9.4. I assume that 7.9.0 - is some internal Node instance which is used by VSCode debugger.

Is it possible make VSCode debugger to use Node version installed on a developer's machine, not the internal one?

Comment: Found similar question here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18253 . Considering what they say, the answer to my question is "No": "VS Code runs extensions on the node version that is built into electron (on which VS Code is based). This cannot be changed."

Comment: Can you compile node-oracledb from source code?  The installation instructions include the steps.

Comment: The thing is I can't because of the proxy issues at my office computer. And there is no official precompiled library of oracledb for Node 7.9.0 . But if to compile source is the easiest way to get oracledb to work with Node 7.9.0, I will go in this direction. Also have posted a comment [here](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/818#issuecomment-366311171) . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to make the VS Code debugger use a different version of Node.js, it is possible to compile native modules (like node-oracledb) for the target version of Node.js. Here are [some details](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md).

For VS Code 1.21.1 (which uses Electron 1.7.0), I did the following from a terminal in my extension directory (may need to delete the `oracledb` directory from `node_modules` first):

```
# Electron's version.
export npm_config_target=1.7.0
# The architecture of Electron, can be ia32 or x64.
export npm_config_arch=x64
export npm_config_target_arch=x64
# Download headers for Electron.
export npm_config_disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron
# Tell node-pre-gyp that we are building for Electron.
export npm_config_runtime=electron
# Tell node-pre-gyp to build module from source code.
export npm_config_build_from_source=true
# Install all dependencies, and store cache to ~/.electron-gyp.
HOME=~/.electron-gyp npm install
```

The last line kicked off an npm install which compiled the binary correctly for the target platform (a custom version of Node.js 7.9.0 that has a newer version of V8 than that version of Node.js usually has).

Comment: `While it's not possible to make the VS Code debugger use a different version of Node.js` - what makes you say so?

Comment: @jayarjo That *seemed* to be the case when I wrote that on March 21, 2018. Are you saying it's changed or was never the case?

Comment: Don't know whether it was not possible before, but now you can specify direct path to the specific `node` executable via `runtimeExecutable` property in the corresponding configuration inside `launch.json` and debugger will take it.

Comment: I think all of that came from this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18253 where it was said that "VS Code runs extensions on the node version that is built into electron (on which VS Code is based). This cannot be changed." I think what you're saying is that I should reference extensions and not the debugger, is that right?

Comment: “[Now] you can specify direct path to the specific `node` executable via `runtimeExecutable` property in the corresponding configuration inside `launch.json` and debugger will take it.” - @jayarjo - what makes you say so? I had `"runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",` from a `yo code` run for an extension, but after applying `"runtimeExecutable": "/bin/node",` Code's TS "debug console" still gives `process.execPath.startsWith('/App') == true` and version is still bad. Lemme know if you want a Q to be able to get an accept from me :) any input is welcome